# Angularjs: Why does it execute function in ng-if when I click on table row?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-if

I have code on https://jsfiddle.net/8t45enfg/2/
The source code is quite simple, suppose the array **list** have only one element
HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
   <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Job</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="a in list" ng-click='doClick()'>
        <td ng-if='doCheck()'>{{ a.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ a.age }}</td>
        <td>{{ a.job }}</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Js code

```
module.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [ { name: 'test', age: 100, job: 'IT'} ]
  $scope.doClick = function() {
    console.log('doClick');
  }
  $scope.doCheck = function() {
    console.log('doCheck');
    return true;
  }
});
```

1. When I run my code, **doCheck()** is executed twice, why? It should be executed once
2. The main question is when I click on data row, both **doCheck** and **doClick** are called, I thought it would call just **doClick**, not **doCheck**, because I had no action on **doCheck**. This made me difficult to understand

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a complete expert on the topic but here is my understanding of your problem.

Whenever a change is made on your page, the page is set to "dirty" and when the next cycle hits the `ng-if`, it will be re-evaluated.

So to answer your first question, the `ng-if` is evaluated when it is loaded (calling `doCheck()`), then the rest of the page is loaded, causing the page to be set to "dirty", so the `ng-if` is re-evaluated, causing `doCheck()` to be called again.

This causes "doCheck" to appear twice.

This is the same for your second question. Whenever you click, the `doCheck()` is re-evaluated, causing both `doClick()` and `doCheck()` to be called.
If you want to avoid `doCheck()` being called each time, use a variable in your `ng-if`, then create a function to change that variable.

I hope that helps, I'm sure some angular wizard will be able to give you a better answer!

Answer (score 0):

It is because of **Angular’s Digest Cycle**

Here are some important quote from [Dave Ceddia Blog — Controller Function Is Executed Multiple Times](https://daveceddia.com/controller-function-executed-multiple-times/) to help you understand the reason:

> ## Angular’s Digest Cycle
>
> What you are seeing is the **digest cycle** at work. The digest cycle is
>   how Angular’s auto-update magic works – it’s the reason that typing
>   into an input box automatically updates anything that refers to its
>   value.
>
> When the digest cycle runs, it effectively redraws everything that
>   might have changed on the page.
>
> Angular uses some tricks to find “everything that might have changed”,
>   and the main technique is **watchers**. These watchers are created
>   automatically when you use directives like `ng-if` and `ng-class`, and
>   when you use bindings like `{{ yourBindingHere }}`.
>
> Each one of those things registers a watcher. When Angular’s digest
>   cycle runs, every watcher is asked to update its state. In the case of
>   `ng-class`, it will re-run the function bound to it, to see if anything
>   needs to change. This is why your controller function runs multiple
>   times, and it’ll run again each time something changes on the page.

Answer (score 0):

For the **Q1**.
    doCheck() is the function which you created, which mean it will check each time when the html run. If you want to do check condition for the  tag then you must use the variable rather than the function.

For the **Q2**.
   When you click the row **doClick** will fire and then the **doCheck** function also will run because you have used that function in the **ng-if** condition, So that will re-evaluate again

I hope this answer will help you to understand. I have modified your code with small changes.

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Job</th>
  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="a in list" ng-click='doClick()'>
    <td ng-if='doCheckCondition'>{{ a.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ a.age }}</td>
    <td>{{ a.job }}</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

JS Script

```
module.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [ { name: 'test', age: 100, job: 'IT'} ]
  $scope.doClick = function() {
     console.log('doClick');

     //Do something and set it true the $scope.doCheckCondition
  }
  $scope.doCheckCondition = false
```